# android ksoap2 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 Library to parse webservice

URL : `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPeernalty.svc`

NameSpace :  `http://tempuri.org/`

SOAP_ACTION : `http://tempuri.org/IInquiryPenalty/GetTraffics`

METHOD_NAME : 'gettraffic'

That's My Code :

```
    try {

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName("City");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getCity());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Username");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getLetter());
        propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("SerialType");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getSeri());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Serial");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getSerial());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Date");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getDate());
        propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        // httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        Log.i(TAG, "getSoapResponse: " + response.getPropertyCount());

        soapCallback.onCallback(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getSoapResponse: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        soapCallback.onCallback(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error :

```
E/Services_TAG: getSoapResponse: size <= 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:101)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:251)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
at ir.aseman.app.soaptest.provider.Services.getSoapResponse(Services.java:58)
at ir.aseman.app.soaptest.Activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when open http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPeernalty.svc?wsdl iin browser
it shows :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="InquiryPenalty" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPenalty.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPenalty.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPenalty.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TTO.InquiryPenalty.Models"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IInquiryPenalty_GetTraffics_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTraffics"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IInquiryPenalty_GetTraffics_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTrafficsResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IInquiryPenalty">
<wsdl:operation name="GetTraffics">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInquiryPenalty/GetTraffics" message="tns:IInquiryPenalty_GetTraffics_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInquiryPenalty/GetTrafficsResponse" message="tns:IInquiryPenalty_GetTraffics_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IInquiryPenalty" type="tns:IInquiryPenalty">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetTraffics">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IInquiryPenalty/GetTraffics" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="InquiryPenalty">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IInquiryPenalty" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IInquiryPenalty">
<soap:address location="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/InquiryPenalty/InquiryPenalty.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Output is : `size <= 0`

How can Solve It ?

Comment: check NameSpace, SOAP_ACTION And METHOD_NAME with server side

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
try {

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName("City");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getCity());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Username");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getLetter());
        propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("SerialType");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getSeri());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Serial");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getSerial());
        propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
        propertyInfo.setName("Date");
        propertyInfo.setValue(model.getDate());
        propertyInfo.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new 
        SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
         String responsesuccess = response.toString();
       // SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        Log.i(TAG, "getSoapResponse: " + responsesuccess);

        //soapCallback.onCallback(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getSoapResponse: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        soapCallback.onCallback(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: is SoapObject unUsable Or SoapPrimitive ?  either has same name

Comment: To get response from server use SoapPrimitive. avoid SoapObject for now

Comment: Error happened on httpTransportSE.call 
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0

Comment: once check NAMESPACE and METHOD_NAME from server side and in your code

Comment: i dont have any access to server side codes or develper, can i get them from URL

Comment: yup check in URL by passsing all the parameters

Comment: can you explain any more ?

Comment: hit the URL in chrome after that pass all the required parameters and check the response there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149383/discussion-between-androsco-and-sunil-p).

Comment: you mean InquiryPenalty.svc?wsdl&key1=value1&key2=value2 or InquiryPenalty.svc?key1=value1&key2=value2

Answer (score 1):

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```

Instead of

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

Comment: It will help you hopefully.

Comment: it was not my problem, checked before